# Accord de l'adjectif se rapportant à des noms de genres différents

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Lorsque l'adjectif se rapporte à deux noms, l'un masculin, l'autre féminin, comment doit-on l'accorder ?

Exemple: laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte ?

> Un avocat *ou* une banane pourri.
>
> Un avocat *ou* une banane pourri**e**.

Comment: Ici, pourri est un adjectif, pas un participe passé

Comment: Oui, mais il y a le cas du "ou" inclusif et celui du "ou" exclusif. Dans ce dernier cas, le bât blesse...
Exemple : Pierre ou Jeanne sera élu
Il est clair qu'ici le "ou" est exclusif, ce sera forcément l'un ou l'autre, le participe (ou l'adjectif, peu importe...) devra donc se mettre au singulier, mais à quel genre ?
Y aurait-il un vide grammatical ici ? cela fait des années que je cherche des exemples dans une foule d'ouvrages de référence, y compris les plus "professionnels", et de sites internet et ne trouve aucun exemple en ce qui concerne l'accord (en matière de genre) en présence d'un "o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un avocat (nom masculin) ou une banane (nom féminin) pourri (adjectif qualificatif).
Question : comment se fait l'accord de l'adjectif ?

---

> L’adjectif qui se rapporte à plusieurs noms ou pronoms coordonnés prend la marque du pluriel et le genre des mots qualifiés. S’ils sont de genres différents, l’adjectif prend le genre indifférencié, c’est-à-dire le masculin. (*[Les adjectifs dans la langue française](http://www.adjectifs.com/qualificatifs-accord.html)*)

Donc si les deux sont pourris il faut écrire :

> Un avocat ou une banane pourris.

Ceci dit on peut très bien écrire :

> Un avocat ou une banane pourrie.

qui veut dire que seule la banane est pourrie.

Ou :

> Un avocat pourri ou une banane.

Par contre :

> <strike>Un avocat ou une banane pourri.</strike>

est agrammatical selon les règles communément admises.

Voir aussi :

- L'accord de l'adjectif sur [Français facile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-53621.php) (Règles particulières).
- Accord de l'adjectif sur [Reverso](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_01_accord_de_ladjectif.shtml)
- L'Adjectif qualificatif au pluriel sur [Grammaire AIDENET](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire09a.htm) (Accord suivant le sens de la phrase)
- Accorder l'adjectif épithète se rapportant à plusieurs noms. [Bescherelle](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-fChAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=accord%20de%20l%27adjectif%20avec%20deux%20noms%20diff%C3%A9rents%20genre&source=bl&ots=ES_6H_RP_K&sig=MDxyj11K2uxXpX9DwOFNrfuKrGA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip__rEyMrUAhUOLVAKHfhFA484FBDoAQgnMAE#v=onepage&q=accord%20de%20l%27adjectif%20avec%20deux%20noms%20diff%C3%A9rents%20genre&f=false).

Et aussi ce [billet](http://leplus.nouvelobs.com/contribution/341359-le-masculin-l-emporte-sur-le-feminin-et-si-les-feministes-arretaient-la-grammaire.html) d'une « coach en orthographe » : *Le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin : et si les féministes arrêtaient la grammaire ?*.

Comment: +1 pour la référence au machisme de la langue française

Comment: En revanche, il faut écrire: « une banane ou un avocat marron » ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Tout à fait, de même des  avocats et des bananes orange, framboise, noisette, abricot... en vertu de la règle qu'ils  sont toujours invariables !

Comment: Oui, mais c'est plus rigolo avec [avocat marron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_d%27idiotismes_chromatiques_fran%C3%A7ais#Marron).

Comment: J'en concède  !!!